# How to run a function rowise using purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use this dataset

```
dd <- cross_df(list(p = c(.1, .5, .9), x = c(0:2))) 

# A tibble: 9 x 2
      p     x
  <dbl> <int>
1   0.1     0
2   0.5     0
3   0.9     0
4   0.1     1
5   0.5     1
6   0.9     1
7   0.1     2
8   0.5     2
9   0.9     2
```

To run a function `dbinom` for each row. For instance, the first row would be:

```
binom(x = 0, size = 2, prob = .1)
```

I am trying using `purrr` like this, but I get an error:

```
dd %>%  
  map2_dbl(.x = .$p, .y = .$x, ~ dbinom(x = .y, size = 2, prob = .x))
Error: Can't convert a list to function
```

Comment: you could just use `dplyr::rowwise()`, did you specifically want purrr?

Comment: @zacdav I meant to practice a bit with `purrr` so yes I would love to do it in `purrr`

Comment: Obviously this is overlooking that `dbinom` is vectorised, so you could just do `dbinom(dd$x, dd$p, size=2)` or even `do.call(dbinom, c(dd,size=2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pipe, the first parameter is implicitly the data frame (or whatever you're piping in), which doesn't work for `map` functions unless you want to iterate across the columns (which you don't here). Instead, either wrap it in dplyr:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dd <- cross_df(list(p = c(.1, .5, .9), 
                    x = c(0:2))) 

dd %>% mutate(binom_density = map2_dbl(x, p, dbinom, size = 2))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>       p     x binom_density
#>   <dbl> <int>         <dbl>
#> 1   0.1     0          0.81
#> 2   0.5     0          0.25
#> 3   0.9     0          0.01
#> 4   0.1     1          0.18
#> 5   0.5     1          0.50
#> 6   0.9     1          0.18
#> 7   0.1     2          0.01
#> 8   0.5     2          0.25
#> 9   0.9     2          0.81
```

or in braces, so you can specify where the data frame goes with `.`:

```r
dd %>% {map2_dbl(.$x, .$p, dbinom, size = 2)}
#> [1] 0.81 0.25 0.01 0.18 0.50 0.18 0.01 0.25 0.81
```

An option you can use without braces (and with more than two parameters) is `pmap`, which iterates in parallel across whatever you pass it, which for a data frame means operating rowwise:

```r
dd %>% pmap_dbl(~dbinom(..2, ..1, size = 2))
#> [1] 0.81 0.25 0.01 0.18 0.50 0.18 0.01 0.25 0.81
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the braces but I am not sure I understand what they do...I thought that `.` could be used as a pronoun to call `dd` anywhere in the function, is this incorrect?

Comment: Correct, but if you do anything with `.` (like subset it), it will still get piped into the first parameter. The braces stop that from happening, and _only_ pass it where you explicitly put a `.`.